# Doctrine 3 Way Mapping

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I need some help getting my head around a 3 way mapping.

I have an entity Student and an entity Parent, obviously one parent can have many students and vice versa, but i need additional information between each parent and student that will be different for each one.

Perhaps we have the following data:

Student A - Parent A (no responsibility) , Parent B (has responsibility) - even though one parent holds legal responsibility and the other doesn't, they are both still parents of the same student.

Student B - Parent A (has responsibility), Parent B (has responsibility) - in this case another student has the same parents but this time they both have legal responsibility.

To start basic entities i would have:

```
class Student
{
    // normally would have a ManyToMany here to link parents, but i need the 3rd entity
    // to hold whether this student's parent has legal responsibility or not
}

class Parent
{
    // normally again would have ManyToMany here to link students to the parent
}

class ParentStudent
{
    /**
    * @var boolean
    * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":true})
    */
    private $responsibility = true;

    // it's this part where i link student to parent and vice versa that's becoming confusing
}
```

Comment: Drop the many to many relation between parent and student and replace it with one to many relations with the ParentStudent entity.  It's the most straight forward approach when your many to many relation needs additional attributes.

Comment: @Cerad could you give an example please? Finding it difficult to visualise it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical Many to Many relationship with edge data / relationship data use case.

You Actually have relationship data class with extra meta data about their relationship, thus it becomes an Entity and you access it just like any other Entity class. Think this relation in terms of graph, nodes and edges. Your Student and Parent Entities are nodes while relationship between them is an edge with weight true/false (i.e 0/1).

For RDBMS, you solve it by introducing 3 entities:

1. `Student`
2. `Parent`
3. `ParentStudent` or `StudentParent` whichever suits and rhymes better with application

You can have as much as data to this relationship and also map it's ID to other relevant data to this association as it is an entity now.

Further You have Following relationships with each other which goes from OneToMany with intermediate entity and ManyToOne mapping inverse side, ultimately connecting both entities as ManyToMany via `ParentStudent` Entity:

```
<?php 
/*
* @ORM\Entity()
*/
class Student  {
     /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
     private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ParentStudent", mappedBy="student", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
      private $parentStudent;
}

/*
* @ORM\Entity()
*/    
class Parent  {
     /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
     private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ParentStudent", mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
      private $parentStudent;
}

/*
* @ORM\Entity()
*/
class ParentStudent  {

     /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Parent", inversedBy="parentStudent")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Student", inversedBy="parentStudent")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $student;

    /**
    * @var boolean
    * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":true})
    */
    private $responsibility = true;
}
```